# jOOQ, Pojos, and Database First Design

Tags: jooq

I'm creating an application and I'm a bit confused about the current state of jOOQ. It's my first time using jOOQ for everything including CRUD so I might be missing some stuff.

I know DAOs and probably Pojos are getting [deprecated](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5984), however, I can't wrap my head around how to deal with this in a Database First [Design](https://blog.jooq.org/2018/06/06/truth-first-or-why-you-should-mostly-implement-database-first-designs/).

The easiest thing I can do is create my own Pojos but then we are back to the usual JPA Entity files, which will not map correctly with the Record if the database has changed.

1) Does deprecating generated pojos imply that I will have to use my own Pojo source generator in the future?

2) Should I have a custom mapper that will throw an exception when Pojo can't map fields with the Record object?

3) Is the best approach to keep using the generated pojos for now? It's not a huge application but I have to pick a strategy and use it in most of the database services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default way to do CRUD in jOOQ is to use the [`UpdatableRecord`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/UpdatableRecord.html) classes produced by the code generator. See also: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/crud-with-updatablerecords

Pojos aren't getting deprecated. The issue description of [#5984](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5984) was outdated, the comments were more up to date. I've updated the issue description to reflect this.

> 1) Does deprecating generated pojos imply that I will have to use my own Pojo source generator in the future?

No, see above.

> 2) Should I have a custom mapper that will throw an exception when Pojo can't map fields with the Record object?

That depends what your pojos should do. If you use jOOQ's generated ones, then the out of the box [`DefaultRecordMapper`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DefaultRecordMapper.html) will always be able to map them

> 3) Is the best approach to keep using the generated pojos for now? It's not a huge application but I have to pick a strategy and use it in most of the database services.

You probably don't need POJOs, `UpdatableRecord` will be enough in most cases. POJOs are there to allow for transferring data without any jOOQ dependency, e.g. between servers.

Comment: Thanks Lukas, I decided to go with your suggestion for now. I have also created a DAO that extends the DAOImpl with my POJO, just for backup until I feel more comfortable with the API. 

I have a question though, using the DSL, I can return data in my POJO using fetchAnyInto(), fetchInto(). 

Is there an equivalent for the UpdatableRecord API? fetchSingle().into() looks similar but I fear there might be null issues with it.

Comment: @GeorgeSofianos: `fetchSingle()` will never return null but throw an exception if no record was found. `Record.into()` works the same way as all the other `into()` methods, but indeed, your record might be `null`. You could call `Result.map(r -> r.into(X.class))`. There are many options.

Comment: Thanks, I've read the interface Javadoc and it's clear which methods return null and which don't. Should be easier to work with JOOQ now :)